# Get current job name in Github Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to reference the running job name in one of its steps. These are the options Github gives us: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-context. The closer one I see is "job.container.id". Would that give me the name I set to the job? It doesn't sound like it. Unfortunately, I can't no longer test this since I exceeded the limit of free Github Actions usage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`github.job` might get you the job name

Link to documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

[image]

Comment: job_id != job name.

Comment: I agree, but the documentation didn't have name back then. However now it is updated 
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idname

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong because `job.name` retrieves the workflow-job name and when using a matrix you will have multiple jobs based on that and their names will likely be different (usually configured via matrix.name). I am still looking for the right way to retrieve the name...

Comment: Just for some clarity, `github.job` does not get you the `job.name` but it does get you the `id` of the `job`, which doesn't allow spaces, etc. For example, if the `job`'s `id` is `assemble_apk` and you named it `"Assemble APK"`, using `github.job` will return `assemble_apk`, not `Assemble APK`, but in our case that was the most useful since we were using it for a log file name and didn't want any spaces or anything.

Comment: `job.name` gives an empty string, and so does `github.job.name`. Which property did you mean?

Comment: `job.name` is only available within the execution `steps` of the job. So this might be the reason you are not getting a value.

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Comment: Kindly fix the answer with information on how to use `github.job` in order to resolve the name at `jobs.<job-id>.name`, ie. how to combine them?

Answer (score -1):

Update 2023: The current method for getting the current job name:

```
      - name: Get job name
        run: |
          # Both work:
          echo "Job name is $GITHUB_JOB"
          echo "How about ${{ github.jobs[github.job].name }}"
```

Comment: GITHUB_JOB actually gives the job id