# How to access the caller Workflow name in a Github Composite Action?

Tags: github-actions

I created a Github Actions composite action and want to retrieve the caller Workflow's name.

I tried `github.run-name` but it resolved to an empty string. Example code is below. Also I considered an `input` instead but seemed it would add unnecessary complexity.

Callee Workflow

```
name: Build App
jobs:
  build_app:
    runs-on: [...]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ./.github/actions/post-to-slack
```

Composite Action

```
name: Post to Slack
description: Posts the results of a Workflow to the Slack channel
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0
      with:
        channel-id: 'build-results'
        slack-message: "${{ github.run-name }} completed. The status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

^ I expected `github.run-name` to return `Build App`

Comment: Can you please specify what information you would like to have? Perhaps that would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611978/get-current-job-name-in-github-actions-workflow

Comment: I added more info about what is expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run-name` refers to the workflow syntax and is: ["The name for workflow runs generated from the workflow."](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name).

With [`github.workflow`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) you can refer to the GitHub context and get information about workflow runs, like this:

```yaml
name: Post to Slack
description: Posts the results of a Workflow to the Slack channel
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0
      with:
        channel-id: 'build-results'
        slack-message: "${{ github.workflow }} completed. The status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

Workflow run log:

[image: GitHub workflow run log]

*Note that I was copying your code without properly setting up the action, thus the error, but you can see the variable was resolved correctly to the Build App workflow in the `slack-message`.*

Comment: To add to this great answer, `run-name` is not actually part of the `github` context, but rather a section in the workflow, similar to the `name` section.

Comment: @babaislove this is an important detail, thanks for pointing it out, I have added it to the answer.